# Does it have an advantage when attaching 'self' to a new defined variable in a python class function?

Tags: python

I wonder if there's any advantage in using 'self' when defining a variable in a class function.

For example:

```
class Pay():     
    def __init__(self, cost):    
        self.deposit = get_from_web_or_somewhere_else    
        if deposit > cost:    
            self.pay()   

    def pay(self):   
        ...
```

In this case, a new variable *deposit* is defined as a self variable.

What I have understood so far is that a newly defined variable in a class cannot be accessed from outside, and even though there's the same named global variable, local variable will be read first.

But I happened to see a code that uses such defining, and it made me curious.

Is this really an unnecessary thing? or does it have an advantage or a difference?

Comment: Well, is it supposed to be an instance attribute or just a local function variable? It's a question of what it's supposed to do, neither is "unnecessary".

Comment: You have to understand what the difference between classes, instances, local and global variables is. This is good article with explanations. [explanation](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/understanding-class-and-instance-variables-in-python-3)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use self it will be a variable inside the object which you can access. Also from the outside.

```
class Pay_self():

    def __init__(self, cost):
        self.deposit = cost

ps = Pay_self(10)
print(ps.deposit)
ps.deposit = 20
print(ps.deposit)
```

Result

```
10
20
```

If you don't use self it is a temporary variable inside the init function.

```
class Pay_not_self():

    def __init__(self, cost):
        deposit = cost


pns = Pay_not_self(10)
try:
    print(pns.deposit)
except Exception as e:
    print(str(e))
```

Result

```
'Pay_not_self' object has no attribute 'deposit'
```

If however you assign a value to the non existing variable it will be created.

```
class Pay_not_self():

    def __init__(self, cost):
        deposit = cost


pns = Pay_not_self(10)
try:
    print(pns.deposit)
except Exception as e:
    print(str(e))

pns.deposit = 20
print(pns.deposit)
```

Result

```
'Pay_not_self' object has no attribute 'deposit'
20
```

So I guess best practice is using self if it isn't a temporary variable.

Answer (score 1):

In your given code, `self.deposit` is an Instance attribute and you can simply use it in all the methods in the class by writing `self.deposit`. But `deposit` only is a local variable of `__init__()` function. So, this is no sense of it being an unnecessary thing, it completely depends on your need.